# How to prevent certain inputs on certain forms using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently had a good setup for preventing gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc. emails from being able to be submitted on our forms for requesting a demo for our company. However, we now have multiple forms on certain pages, some of which we will allow personal emails.

My question is how do I adjust the following script to prohibit the input on a particular form id? Is it possible to simply add something that detects the form ID (let's call it #form-id for now).

```
// EMAIL DOMAINS TO BLOCK
var emailList = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!icloud.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!aol.com)

// ALERT MESSAGE TO BE SHOWN
var emailAlert = 'Please input a valid work email address (NOT Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo, etc.)'

// VALIDATE
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  $("input[type=email]").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (emailList.test(email)) {
        (this).setCustomValidity('');
    } else {
      (this).setCustomValidity(emailAlert);
    }
  })
})

// PREVENTS ALERT FROM APPEARING WITH EACH KEYPRESS
$('input[type=email]').on('input', function() {
  (this).setCustomValidity('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much else about your situation, in basic principle you should be able to scope your code by modifying the selector portion of your jquery function calls.

For example if you wanted to enact this validation only on the form with id  `#form-id` in theory you should be able to change your code to this:

```
$('#form-id input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  $("#form-id input[type=email]").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (emailList.test(email)) {
        (this).setCustomValidity('');
    } else {
      (this).setCustomValidity(emailAlert);
    }
  })
})

// PREVENTS ALERT FROM APPEARING WITH EACH KEYPRESS
$('#form-id input[type=email]').on('input', function() {
  (this).setCustomValidity('');
});
```

The format of this - two sub selectors seperated by a space - means that the 2nd sub-selector will only match when it appears inside the first sub-selector.

Consider example `#form-id input[type=submit]`

This selector will match on inputs of type submit found inside your form (or any parent element) with id `form-id`

To do the opposite you could change the selector to:

`form:not(#form-id) input[type=submit]`

Comment: This worked incredibly. Thank you so much for your help. It's also taught me how to apply form IDs in jquery. Sorry for such a simple question, it was taking me forever to find a solution.

Comment: Happy it helped, there's a little checkmark next to this answer that you can click when an answer is accepted. If you do this the author of the best answer gets points toward their reputation.